# Disabling touch screen on Ubuntu

Tags: touchscreen

I am trying to disable the touch screen on my Dell inspiron 15 7000. When I run the xinput --list, I get this list.

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ 2.4G Mouse                                id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DELL07EC:00 06CB:7E92 Touchpad            id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN2097:00 04F3:2504                     id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=20   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate           id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate           id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ELAN2097:00 04F3:2504 Pen                 id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel Virtual Button driver               id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
```

Please which one of them (ids) is for the touch screen?

Comment: I reckon DELL07EC:00 06CB:7E92

Comment: On Dell XPS 9380, the device was ELAN... It's easy enough to disable and check if it disabled the right thing using `xinput disable <num>`

Answer (score 1):

vanadium is right, it is id 13.  To disable type:

```
xinput disable 13
```

To enable:

```
xinput enable 13
```

To disable permanently, you'll need to add this on boot:

```
crontab -e
```

add line:

```
@reboot  xinput disable $(xinput --list | grep DELL07EC | head -n 1 | awk -F '           ' '{print $2}' | awk '{print $1}' | sed s/id=//)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Disabling touch screen on Linux

I have a dell inspiron 5557 laptop with broken touchscreen. The cursor jumps and clicks randomically each few seconds making the BIOS utility and graphic interfaces unusable and here is how I disabled it:

### Solution:

- Press Alt+F3 to open a console;
- Edit /etc/rc.local to disable the touchscreen device;
- Make /etc/rc.local executable and reboot.

```sh
$ sudo nano /etc/rc.local
  #!/bin/sh
  ls -1 /sys/bus/hid/drivers/hid-multitouch | grep 2A94:5241 > /sys/bus/hid/drivers/hid-multitouch/unbind
$ sudo chmod +x /etc.rc.local
$ reboot
```

### How to find the correct device:

If your laptop is not exactly the same as mine, you may need to find the correct usb device to disable it:

```sh
$ lsusb | grep -i touch
  Bus 001 Device 006: ID 2a94:5241 G2Touch Multi-Touch(...)
```

```sh
$ cd /sys/bus/hid/drivers/hid-multitouch
$ ls -1
  0003:2A94:5241.0006
  0018:06CB:7621.0001
  bind
  (...)
```

then, test it:

```sh
$ sudo bash
$ cd /sys/bus/hid/drivers/hid-multitouch
$ echo "0003:2A94:5241.0006" > unbind
$ killall -9 Xorg
```

In my case, the gnome become unresponsive when I disabled the device. That is why I include a `killall -9 Xorg` in the above example.

If your device is AAAA:BBBB:CCCC:DDDD, use the AAAA:BBBB:CCCC or BBBB:CCCC as deviceid on the /etc/rc.local script. The last 4 digits changed often to me.